# Upgraded graphics card, wireless not fully working

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, graphics-card, upgrade, hardware-failure

I just upgraded my graphics card on my desktop. My wireless no longer fully works. I have already ensured that that the card has sufficient power; manufacturer suggests a minimum of 750w and that is what I have. When I say the wireless no longer fully works I mean I can ping and navigate the Steam store (which is effectively a browser) in the Steam client; but I can't use Chrome/Firefox. By can't use Chrome/Firefox I mean when I try to use Chrome, Firefox, or IE none will bring up any webpage; not only that but other systems that require internet access can not reach the internet (AVG can't update).

Suggestions? The wireless is connected as a USB dongle and I swapped it with another and same results. The Power supply is brand new.

I put the old graphics card in and I still have the same problem.

The computer uses Windows 7. I have tried using an Ubuntu live DVD and the wireless works fine using that (Ubuntu 12.04).

I have tried a wired connection and I get the same results.

I have checked virus/firewall settings to no avail.

Comment: Try reinstalling the most current drivers for the graphics card and wireless adapter

Comment: This is good advice. I have re-installed the drivers for the graphics card twice; once using the driver on disc and the other from off the web (via another machine). I also re-installed the wireless USB device's driver. Neither helped and the problem persists.

Comment: You forgot to describe the problem. What happens when you try to use Chrome or Firefox? How far do you get? What goes wrong? Do you get an error message?

Comment: I've updated the description to elaborate on what happens with the browsers: when trying to use Chrome, Firefox, or IE none will bring up any webpage; not only that but other systems that require internet access can not reach the internet (AVG can't update).

Comment: open a command prompt by opening the start menu and typing "cmd" (without the quotes!)and pressing enter.  in the little black command prompt window, enter "ping google.com" (without quotes) and press enter.  Please report on your results.

Comment: As I mentioned in the description I can ping fine; however I only tried pinging an IP. I tried again and this time did google.com as you suggested; it pings fine.